# Sometimes can't ping router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ping

I have a TP Link tl-wr1043nd v1 router with gargoyle 1.6.1 on it.  At least once or twice a day, my internet breaks for a couple minutes.  When I try to ping the router it will output:

```
PING 192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
```

It doesn't say that the host is unreachable; it just hangs.

I just captured it with wireshark when it happened, but have no idea what I'm looking for or where to go from here.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you connected via WiFi or Ethernet? It's either the transport layer ( = cable / wifi) that fails, or the router that hangs.

Comment: The cable/wifi would be the Physical Layer (in the [OSI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model) model) or Link Layer (in the [TCP/IP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP/IP_model) model), not Transport Layer, which in both models deals with things like TCP, UDP, ICMP, and other similar protocols.

Comment: Wifi drops like that are actually fairly common due to various interfering factors, such as cordless phones, microwaves, or other sources of electromagnetic interference.  2.4 ghz cordless phones are pretty notorious about it, given that they use the same spectrum as 802.11 B/G/N.

Comment: Nicolas, I'm connected via Wifi.

Comment: 0xDAFACADE, it happens even when I'm not microwaving anything and I have a phone that uses 1.9 ghz.  Is it possible that it still interferes or could it be my neighbors?

Answer (score 0):

The 2.4GHz band is pretty much saturated, especially if you live in a dense urban area. Possible sources of interference include the use of Bluetooth devices, other access points and any other wireless transmitter operating in the same frequency band.

You can try to change the channel your Access Point uses to a less crowded one (you can check with "Wifi Analyzer" if you have an android phone) or better, switch to the 5GHz band. Unfortunately, the router you are using only operates in the 2.4GHz band, but this option is worth considering if you need a stable WiFi connection in a dense area.

You could also lay down an ethernet cable, or have a look at CPL adapters. They don't cost that much nowadays (around 30€ for a pair).